# импорт текстовых файлов в MySQL через PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Имеется "папка" в которую сваливаем по сети данные с лабораторного стенда.
Препод как в золотой рыбке хочет все больше и больше :)
Пытаемся загнать данные в таблицу MySQL и как-то зависли c  fgetcsv...
кол-во файлов в день бывает разным. Структура всегда одинакова, названия тоже - добавляется только цифра в названии файла. 
Вот пример собранных данных - https://dropmefiles.com/WruWJ.

Помогите пожалуйста бедным студентам - понятно что долги копить плохо :(

Comment: Загрузить на сервер (MySQL-сервер в смысле) и [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html). А заниматься [censored], прокачивая эту хрень сквозь PHP - ну несерьёзно... на нём разве что выполнить (да и то - средствами ОС) конкатенацию всей этой пачки в один файл и загрузку в @@secure_file_priv.

Comment: а как пачку в один сделать - данные то разные

Comment: `copy *.* total.csv`

Comment: начинается карусель....у нас дата 13-08-2018, в базе формат DATA - другой...

Comment: *у нас дата 13-08-2018, в базе формат DATA - другой...* и чё? ссылку я дал, оператор SET там описан - крути и преобразовывай данные как тебе заблагорассудится, соответствующая функция [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) у MySQL имеeтся.